# Are there any specific resources to use for creating a shiny app that uploads a file and plots a selected column?

Tags: r, shiny, upload

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

if (!require("okcupiddata")) install.packages("okcupiddata")
library(okcupiddata)
D=sample_n(profiles, 5000)
write.csv(D, file="~/Downloads/OKCupid.csv", row.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel(title = "Uploading Your File"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            width = 2,
            ## Create a file upload control
            fileInput(inputId = "file",
                      label = "Choose Your File:",
                      accept = c(".txt", ".csv")),
            ## Use html tag hr (horizontal rule) to make a horizontal separator
            hr(),
            ## Make a h5 heading
            h5("Max file size is 2M"),
            ## Create a checkbox that can be used to specify logical values.
            checkboxInput(inputId = "header",
                          label = "Header",
                          value = TRUE),
            ## Create a set of radio buttons used to select an item from a list.
            radioButtons(inputId = "sep",
                         label = "Separator",
                         choices = c(Comma = ",", Space = " ", Tab = "\t")),
            
            uiOutput("variable")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),
                tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                tabPanel("Plot", plotlyOutput("plot", height = "700px"))
            )
            
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    myData <- reactive({ 
        f = input$file
        if (is.null(f)){
            return(NULL)
            
        } else {
            read.table(f$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep)
            
        }
    })

    #A. Create a drop-down menu to choose a variable
    output$variable <- renderUI({
        
        })
    #B. Display the whole table
    output$table <- renderTable({

    })
    
    #C. Summarize the whole table
    output$summary <- renderPrint({
    })
    
    #D. Plot only the selected variable.
    # The code needs to handle both a categorical and numeric variables
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      
})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm stuck on A, B, C, and D. I know to use selectInput() to create a drop down menu, a data frame() function to render a table, a summary() function to render a summary, and a ggplot() function to render both a numeric and categorical plot.I don't know how to correctly reference the selected file and then reference the column from said file. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `myData()[, ]`. The file input seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer completes A, B, C and D. You haven't really shared what kind of plot you need but based on class of the column selected this displays the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(title = "Uploading Your File"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      ## Create a file upload control
      fileInput(inputId = "file",
                label = "Choose Your File:",
                accept = c(".txt", ".csv")),
      ## Use html tag hr (horizontal rule) to make a horizontal separator
      hr(),
      ## Make a h5 heading
      h5("Max file size is 2M"),
      ## Create a checkbox that can be used to specify logical values.
      checkboxInput(inputId = "header",
                    label = "Header",
                    value = TRUE),
      ## Create a set of radio buttons used to select an item from a list.
      radioButtons(inputId = "sep",
                   label = "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",", Space = " ", Tab = "\t")),
      
      uiOutput("variable")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),
        tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
        tabPanel("Plot", plotlyOutput("plot", height = "700px"))
      )
      
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  myData <- reactive({ 
    f = input$file
    if (is.null(f)){
      return(NULL)
      
    } else {
      read.table(f$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep)
      
    }
  })
  
  #A. Create a drop-down menu to choose a variable
  output$variable <- renderUI({
    selectInput('dd', 'Select dropdown', names(myData()))
    
  })
  #B. Display the whole table
  output$table <- renderTable({
     myData()
  })
  
  #C. Summarize the whole table
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(myData())
  })
  
  #D. Plot only the selected variable.
  # The code needs to handle both a categorical and numeric variables
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    if(is.numeric(myData()[[input$dd]]))
      plt <- ggplot(myData(), aes(.data[[input$dd]])) + geom_histogram()
    else 
      plt <- ggplot(myData(), aes(.data[[input$dd]])) + geom_bar()
    ggplotly(plt)
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This worked out perfectly!